# Is there any free/open source map engine for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have a bunch of map images and i wonder if there is any free/open source map engine that I can use for iPhone development. Just like google map api but they are for native development

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [OpenStreetMap](http://OpenStreetMap.org) as a mapping framework rather then the Google API mapping.

1. OpenStreetMap is less restrictive in license terms then Google maps.
2. You can provide better mapping data with OpenStreetMap then with Google maps using custom or predefined mapping layers.

In regards to engines (frameworks/api's) that access the OSM data. Check out the following.

- [route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/)
- [CloudMade](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects)

If you would like to find more information on using OSM on the iPhone/iPod Touch check out the [OSM iPhone Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IPhone)

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is, and it's called [Route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/).  Licensed under licensed under the BSD license.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some frameworks/api's that access the OSM data, I recommend you to have a look at  [Navit](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Navit) (it's an open source projects) and [skobbler's OSM SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com/) (it's a good solutions with a free tier plan that might be large enough for your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is cloudmade.com - its a layer on the OSM and includes an iphone library routing toolkit etc.

Comment: just realized the OSM answer mentions cloudmade so I have voted that up